# Adding automatic kashida/tracking to Arabic text (not kerning)

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, typography

My goal is to add automatic kashida/tracking to my text

for example, see text marked with 1 and 2
the second one (2) has automatic kashida/tracking

[image]

it's also required to apply this to any font ..
[image]

PS: I tried kerning, and it adds white space between words, this is irrelevant to the question.